# Marketing Cloud: send push notification to Mobile Publisher

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, community-builder, mobilepush, push-notification

Do you know if Marketing Cloud can send push notifications to a published app from Mobile Publisher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible, as push notifications from Mobile Studio require the Marketing Cloud Mobile Push SDK being enabled as part of the app - which is not the case for the Salesforce mobile app.

Comment: Thank you very much Lukas for your answer, suddenly you know if in any next release this SDK would be within the apps that are published from Mobile Publisher?

Comment: Do you mean the Salesforce mobile app i.e. Salesforce 1 or do you mean mobile apps published using Salesforce Mobile Publisher?

Comment: @Robs - Marketing Cloud can not push to either of these two, as they don't have the Mobile Push SDK embedded

Comment: @LukasLunow, is there a workaround? I am thinking - MC to update a trigger in the CRM and the CRM will make the Push?

Answer (score 0):

While implementing the Mobile Push SDK doesn't seem like a valid option, on "paper" the following data flow would work within the context of Journey Builder when MC Connect is in place, and assuming the contacts one would like to push to are all in Sales/Service Cloud:

- Add a JB activity to update a Contact record (or better: a Campaign Member record)
- Have the CRM listen to this event and do the push

There are some limitations still:

Using APEX to trigger a push notification event directly via the API is not supported. Use of FLOW or Process builder is supported.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352329&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1